# New User setup?

Tags: civievent

How do we add a user to our website?  I know you think we need more to this question, but we just want one more staff person to be able to access the backend of the web site and registration.

Erika Dvorske

Comment: Erika, can you please state in your question which CMS you are using for your website? Otherwise it is almost impossible to answer.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are asking how to give a user a CMS account - which would depend on what type of CMS it is - joomla, drupal or wordpress - and if so you will find answers on their documentation i suspect.

If you already have a user but they don't have access, then you need to check their CMS permissions. hth